"errorMessage": "Class not found: org.sfa.request.requesthandler.GetRequestHandler", "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
I used the AWS lambda function to connect with my jar and want to test my handler functions in springboot. But, there is a big problem.
{
"errorMessage": "Class not found: org.sfa.request.requesthandler.GetRequestHandler",
"errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}
this is my code
package org.sfa.request.requesthandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;

import     com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent;
/**

ClassName: GetRequestHandler

Package: org.sfa.request.requesthandler
@Slf4j
public class GetRequestHandler extends BaseRequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {
private static final RequestService requestService = context.getBean(RequestService.class);
@Override
public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent requestEvent, Context lambdaContext) {
try
}


this is my pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"\>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>3.3.1</version>
<relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>org.sfa</groupId>
<artifactId>request</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>request</name>
<description>request</description>
<url/>
<licenses>
<license/>
</licenses>
<developers>
<developer/>
</developers>
<scm>
<connection/>
<developerConnection/>
<tag/>
<url/>
</scm>
<properties>
<java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.7.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.3</version> <!-- 使用最新版本 -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.3</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>




</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <dependencies>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot.experimental/spring-boot-thin-layout -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.28.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>



        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/NOTICE.md</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE.md</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/NOTICE</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/DEPENDENCIES</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/COPYRIGHT</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/license.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/notice.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/NOTICE.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/spring.tooling</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/spring/aot.factories</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/web-fragment.xml</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/versions/*/module-info.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>license.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>notice.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


please check the pacakged jar by unzipping and see if there is GetRequestHandler inside  org/sfa/request/requesthandler/ path. probable cause maybe maven-shade-plugin is accidenlty excluding the handler call from being packaged
